# Prove that subset of complex plane is open or is closed (or both or neither )

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I have subset

$$D = \{z: \text{Re}(z) > 2, \text{Im}(z) \leq1\}$$

So i think that set is not open because contain boundary points, but how prove this?

Let's say it's open. so by defenition we have: For all points of the set, they are contained together with some ball. Let's take an arbitrary point (with the property $\text{Im}(z_0)=1$),
$$z_0 \in D$$

Let's look at the ball with the center at our point. 
$$B_r(z_0) = \{z: |z - z_0|<r\}$$

Where $r>0$ is the positive number. So...

I have a problem with building a contradiction. Intuition tells us that if a number 
$r$ 
has $\text{Im}(r) > 0$
 So we have $z_o + r = c \notin D$

is it close?

Help me develop intuition and technique for this kind of task. (prooving subset of complex plane is open or close)

Comment: It's neither open nor closed.

Comment: Thx bit im need detailed proof!

Comment: Some sets are both open and closed while some sets are not open and not closed. For example the subset $[0,1)$ of the real numbers it not open or closed in the standard topology.

Comment: Thank you! I heard about this example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are in the right way to prove $D$ is not open. It suffices to take $ \ z=z_{0}+\frac{i}{2}r \ $, then $ \ |z-z_{0}|=\frac{r}{2}<r \ $ and $ \Im(z)=1+\frac{r}{2}>1. $

$A \subset \mathbb{C} \ $ is closed if and only if the limit of every convergent sequence $ (z_{n})_{n} \subset A $ is also in $A$.

Take $ \ z_{n}=2+\frac{1}{n} \ $, then $z_{n}\in D$ and $ \lim_{n\to \infty}z_{n}=2 \notin D $. Hence $D$ is not closed.

Note that the only subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ which are both open and closed are $ \emptyset$ and $ \mathbb{C} $, since $\mathbb{C}$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the definition of open sets in metric spaces. $D$ isn't open because a disk centered on $i$ will always have a point outside $D$ so it cannot be entirely contained in $D$. $^cD$ (the complement of D) isn't open either because a disk centered on $2$ will always have a point outside $D$. Hence $D$ is neither open nor closed.

This is not a detailed proof but it's really easy to show an example point (depending on the radius $r$ of the disk) in both cases : $(1+r/2)i$, $2+r/2$.